# Not Sure If My Function Is Classified As Recursive

Tags: recursion, pseudocode

I have some pseudocode here:

```
index = 0
function search(A, n)
    if A[index] == n
        return true
    else
        index += 1
        return search(A, n)

print search ( [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 … 99], 5 )
```

Is this function recursive even with the `index` variable? I know that I'm calling the method inside of itself (which is recursion) but I don't know if proper recursion is allowed to have incrementing variables outside the function.

Comment: it is. it's tail recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  A recursive function is one that calls itself (or may do).  Nothing else it does or does not do is relevant to that definition.  "Does" is to be interpreted in the sense of code or potentiality, not in the sense of what actually happens on any given run.

On the other hand, there are plenty of things that it are *unwise* for a recursive function to do, and depending on a global variable to control its operation is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

suggest you to put it in this way:

```
function search(A, n)
    function aux(i)
        if A[i] == n
            return true
        else
            return aux(i+1)

    return aux(0)
```

it's tail recursive.